# Summing Group Items in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, scope

I have what I think is a fairly simple problem, but can't for the life of me figure out how to do it (SSRS 2008 R2). I'm using a tablix, as I need to display detail data (not just aggregates)

I have rows of data (shipping costs) and job cost distribution

The (abridged) data in the report is

```
TrackNo      ShipCost   NoJobs          JobNo        Job Cost
T1             10.00        1             J1           10.00
T2             10.00        3             J2            3.33
T2             10.00        3             J3            3.33
T2             10.00        3             J4            3.33
```

So, TrackNo T1 may have 1 job associated with it and TrackNo T2 may have 3 jobs associated. I then pro-rata the costs across the jobs. If each shipment costs $10:

- for tracking no T1, job no J1 will get $10.00
- for tracking no T2, jobs J2, J3 & J4 will each get $3.33

I want to have a drill down report like this:

```
TrackNo     Ship Total         No. Jobs         Job No             Job Total
+  T1           10.00              1
                                                  J1                   10.00
+  T2           10.00              2                                                          
                                                  J2                    3.33
                                                  J3                    3.33
                                                  J4                    3.33
```

In my report, group 1 is tracking no; group 2 (child group) is job no.

```
TrackNo
    JobNo
```

Ship Total on the report is `First(Fields!ShipTotal.Value)`

I want to sum the ShipTotal for the entire report (not sum the job totals, as these have rounding errors: e.g. 3.33 * 3 = 9.99)

How can I sum the values shown against group 1 (`First(Fields!ShipTotal.Value)`)? I'm figuring Scope is the way, but I'm lost.

Answer (score 17):

Often this question is asked for older versions of SSRS, so it's nice to answer for a recent version that supports the feature you need. SSRS 2008R2 introduced support for aggregates of aggregates.

In your total box for the report set the expression to be:

```
=SUM( MAX(Fields!ShipTotal.Value, "TrackNo"), "DataSetName")
```

As you mentioned, the Scope is a key part of this. The expression above indicates that SSRS should take the First ShipTotal for each "TrackNo" group, and add those up for every TrackNo group in the dataset. (Substitute your data set name in there, of course.)

Two other two methods to get this result will also work in earlier versions of SSRS as well:

- Use Embedded code to [keep track of the aggregate](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/65/posts/11579/aggregate-of-an-aggregate-function-in-ssrs.aspx).
- Perform the math in your query, return the result with a different dataset, or as a new field with each row.

Comment: does this work in SSRS 2005?  When I tried it i get the error "Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other aggregate functions".

Comment: No, this functionality was added with SSRS 2008R2. There are a few ways to implement this in 2005. One of the most common is using custom code to store a running total, and only adding to it once per group. Something like this: http://devshed.us/Blogs/tabid/227/EntryId/552/SSRS-How-to-get-a-running-total.aspx

Comment: If like me you need the sum in the group footer, you don't need to specify the dataset: `=Sum(Max(Fields!ShipTotal.Value, "TrackNo"))` is enough