# SSRS Nested Aggregation; Sum Max within group

Tags: reporting-services, scope, nested, formula, aggregation

Related questions:

[Summing Group Items in SSRS 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309211/summing-group-items-in-ssrs-2008-r2)

[SSRS sum max by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005166/ssrs-sum-max-by-group)

SSRS 2012. I need to do a nested aggregate, Sum(Max()) on a Matrix with Row Group "Location" and Column Groups "Month" and "Day" respectively.

I have a formula:

```
=Sum(Max(Fields!Cards_Ship.Value, "Day"),"Month")
```

It correctly Sums the Max(Cards_Ship) by day within the Month. **However, it doesn't stay within the scope of the Row Group "Location"**. Location A has the most Sum(Max(Card_Ship)), so that value gets repeated for each location and the total.

I have tried:

```
=Sum(Max(Fields!Cards_Ship.Value, "Day"),"Location")
```

But it won't let me define scope across 2 axes (Row and Colmn).

Your input would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: 
sorry I don't understand the table/data formatting. 
Currect:
Loc MTD 1st  2nd 
A 20 10 10 
B 20 2 2
tot 20 12 12
Expected:
Loc MTD 1st 2nd 
A 20 10 10 
B 4 2 2
tot 24 12 12

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and an expected output from it?

Comment: added above, sorry about the formatting.